# After Adding new value in array previous values of inputs in *ngFor Table get blank

Tags: arrays, angular, html-table, ngfor, angular8

I am creating an project in which i have table of inputs where user makes entry name, description, price, quantity and one checkbox field. in that i have applied for loop to rows and intialized array with one blank value to show one blank row to fill by user then user can click on the button provided in first column.

Where i am pushing another blank value in that array after pushing table updates and also new row gets added in table but previous rows input gets blank.screenshot given below.

**array used for ngfor:**

```
// items table fields
invoiceitems = [
    {
        id: this.idcount,
        name: "",
        description: "",
        price: "",
        qty: "",
        amount: "",
        istax: "",
        selectedItem: {}
    }
];
```

**Table in html:**

```
   <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead class="table-head table-head">
                <tr class="text-white">
                    <th class="invoice-detail-margin">#</th>
                    <th class="invoice-detail-summary">Description</th>
                    <th class="invoice-detail-rate">Rate</th>
                    <th class="invoice-detail-quantity">Qty</th>
                    <th class="invoice-detail-total">Amount</th>
                    <th class="invoice-detail-tax">Tax</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                <tr class="item-row item-row-1 with-tax"
                    *ngFor="let item of invoiceitems; let i = index">
                    <td class="item-row-actions">
                        {{item | json}}
                        <div class="confirm-delete-button">
                            <button type="button" title="Remove Item" (click)="removeitem(i)"
                                style="border-color: rgb(51, 51, 51); color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"
                                class="btn btn-remove table-head plus-minus-btn">
                                <span class="plus-minus-icon-span">
                                    <i class="fas fa-minus"></i>
                                </span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Item #1" class="item-row-summary">
                        <span class="item-row-name">
                            <div class="item-suggest">
                                <div role="combobox" aria-haspopup="listbox"
                                    aria-owns="react-autowhatever-1" aria-expanded="false"
                                    class="react-autosuggest__container">
                                    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" [(ngModel)]="item.name"
                                        aria-autocomplete="list"
                                        aria-controls="react-autowhatever-1" name="item-name"
                                        class="react-autosuggest__input invoice-input"
                                        id="invoice-item-code" placeholder="Item Description">
                                    <!-- 
                                    <ng-select class="custom"
                                        (change)="itemselected(item.selectedItem, i)"
                                        [items]="Items" bindLabel="name" autofocus name="item-name"
                                        [(ngModel)]="item.selectedItem" required>
                                    </ng-select> -->

                                    <div id="react-autowhatever-1" role="listbox"
                                        class="react-autosuggest__suggestions-container">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </span>
                        <span class="item-row-description">
                            <textarea style="min-height: 80px; height: 69px;"
                                [(ngModel)]="item.description" name="item-descrition"
                                class="item-description-input invoice-input"
                                placeholder="Additional details"></textarea>
                        </span>
                    </td>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Here is how i am creating new row :

```
    this.invoiceitems.push({
        id: this.idcount + 1,
        name: "",
        description: "",
        price: "",
        qty: "",
        amount: "",
        istax: "",
        selectedItem: {}
    });
```

**First entry before adding new row :**

[screenshot of first entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWC6u.png)

**After adding new row in table :**

[after new row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlsFf.png)

Comment: is this a form? Also there is toooooo much code, please provide a [mcve]. Please remove all unneccessary. It's enough to just show one property in the question, not all.

Comment: the question is about table so ihave to include whole table

Comment: sure, but you can have a table with a single field, not show all fields. The problem is the same if you have 1 or 100 fields in the table. Your issue is that the row resets to empty, but the amount of fields doesn't matter. It's so much easier to work with when the code is minimal.

Comment: I know I won't sift through all that code and try to find the issue. Help us help you.

Comment: I have reduced to only one field.check new edit

Comment: great, looks cleaner and more readable. Also, I asked before, is this a form?

Comment: table is just in form tag no validation or form dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your answer to my comment, You are using a form, so what you are doing is registering form controls with `ngModel` and the `name` attribute. Since you are using just same `name` for all rows, angular considers that all columns in rows is the same form control, see the template here: **[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qoli5v?file=src/app/app.component.html)** You can see that there is only one value present in form, no matter how many rows you have.

You can solve this by giving each form control an unique name (or remove the form tags). Giving the name attribute an unique name can be used by using the help of index, so instead of this:

```html
<input [(ngModel)]="item.name" name="item-name" placeholder="Item Description">
```

do:

```html
<input [(ngModel)]="item.name" [name]="'item' + i" placeholder="Item Description">
```

where `i` is the index of the item from `*ngFor`. Do the same for all your column fields. Here's a **[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kaja1q?file=src/app/app.component.html)** demonstrating that.